# Condition to buy and sell based on the previous day close

Tags: pine-script

I am new to PineScript. I need help with a simple strategy that

Buys if the price is higher than the price at the close of the previous day.

Sells if the price is lower than the price at the close of the previous day

How can I do that?
Thank you

Comment: Please share what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

Go in the pine editor, click on new -> blank strategy script, you will have a good template for strategies, the conditions should be stated in `longCondition` and `shortCondition`.

```
longCondition = close > close[1]
if (longCondition)
    strategy.entry("My Long Entry Id", strategy.long)

shortCondition = close < close[1]
if (shortCondition)
    strategy.entry("My Short Entry Id", strategy.short)
```

Note that such strategy is already implemented under the name "Bar UpDn Strategy".

Comment: I put the script  in a strategy. but I do not want to buy or sell at every candle unless the price goes again through the close of the previous day...in other words if the price price goes up...it will be with just one order in the market...if the price will come back down and go through the close of the previous day at that time it will sell.